# Spring Security use custom UserDetailsService to store custom User object

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security

I am using Spring security + JPA + custom UserDetailsService. It seems like I can only store

```
String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
```

In the User object. What should I do if I need to sore my custom User object in session after login. I want to save FIRST, LAST, Company and... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own user model, and add all your preferred attributes to it.then Wrap it in your `UserDetails` Implementation, for example

```
public class UserModel {
   private username;
   private password;
   private firstname;
   private lastname;
   .
   .
   .
   etc
}

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

  private UserModel user;

  public UserModel getUser(){
    return user;
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername(){
    return user.getUsername();
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword(){
    return user.getPassword();
  }

}
```

And whenever you need to access your `UserModel` specific attributes, use the `getUser()` method and access your specific fields directly

```
MyUserDetails myUserDetails = (MyUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

UserModel user = myUserDetails.getUser();

String firstname = user.getFirstname();
```

The good point of such an implementation is that you separate the security `UserDetails` implementation from your own `User` implementation which could be for example a managed entity by any ORM framework like Hibernate

Comment: May I ask what is this userDetails there for ? When would I want to use the userDetailsService and its userDetails ? What use case ? In which scenario ? I have implemented a fully working basic authentication for my REST application and wonder if/how/why I should add the userDetails in the mix.

Comment: I think I got an answer to my question. I implemented a custom UserDetailsServiceImpl extending UserDetailsService with a custom UserDetailsWrapper extending UserDetails and using it in the security configuration with a http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService); This allows for my user state to be considered before granting access. For example. if the user lacks a role then he is denied authorization.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few great tutorials out there but if you want short cut with github example check out this question.

[Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526132/could-not-autowire-field-private-org-springframework-security-core-userdetails)

It also has a github rep you can access to get example code, it was done in collaboration with Sprin Sec dev lead.